# How to pass an express.js response object to another module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to pass an Express response object to a different module I have. So in my `server.js` file I have this:

```
const room = require('../controller/rooms_controller')
app.post('/rooms',  function(req, res){
    var name = req.body.roomname
    var loc  = req.body.loc
    room.newRoom(name, loc,  res)
})
```

I am trying to pass the `res` object to the `rooms_controller` module. Now my rooms_controller module looks like this:

```
const Room  = require('../models/room')

exports.newRoom = function(name, loc, res){


    Room.findOne({'location': loc}, function(err, room, res){
        if(err){
            res.send({err: err})
        }
        if(room){
            res.send({room: room})
        }else{
            var newRoom = new Room()
            newRoom.location = loc
            newRoom.name     = name
            newRoom.save(function(error){
                if(err){
                    res.send({ error: error })
                }
                res.send({room: newRoom})
            })
        }
    })



}
```

So in my database the records are getting created but I am getting the `cannot read property send of undefined` error in my terminal.

Comment: This question can be closed as "Not reproducible or caused by a typo", because the answer is rather trivial, and it probably won't help other readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing it correctly but are overwriting res because you redefine it on this line

```
Room.findOne({'location': loc}, function(err, room, res){
```

So res is the response from `Room.findOne` instead of the argument to `newRoom` which is your actual response object. Use a different variable name for one of them.

Comment: `room` is the response from `findOne`, I don't think the callback actually gets passed a third argument at all.

Comment: Although I don't know what the function it is most likely the case @robertklep described which means you can remove the third argument of the callback altogether.